# After upgrade to Yosemite Time Machine says "Disk Full" even if there's 350GB free space

Tags: finder, time-machine, backup, upgrade, macos

I upgraded to Yosemite yesterday, and just now I got a Time Machine alert

> Disk is Full

although there are 350+ GB on the backup disk according to Finder. It said it had deleted an old backup (boo).

Just now I did a manual backup (from the TM preferences panel) and it backed up 2 MB to the free 350GB disk and all was fine.

What gives?  What can I do to make TM happy?

Comment: If you have already a Mavericks backup on it, perhaps you have some conflicts. You have tried to erase your disk ?

Comment: It's not clear if you are looking to [clean up the backups](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/805/) or do something else. Could you edit this if you still are facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If on top of your Mac's hard drive, you are also backuping an external USB drive, you may want to check this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/message/27031297

Answer (score -3):

Try to open Terminal (use spotlight) and type `sudo rm -Rf (Directory to disk)/*`

Comment: You should explain what that does

Comment: People - please don't `sudo rm -rf` anything unless you have a backup and time to reinstall your Mac. This person is just evil for suggesting you delete your entire system...

Comment: What it is doing is it is deleting the disk, Back it up first but it helps because backup drives like to hide extra crap that you cant use